# Mock Angular HttpClient in protractor e2e test

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing

My application is making an http call to my backend immediately on page load. My e2e test is failing because there is no backend running in my ci pipelines.

I have tried using the rxjs catchError piped operator on the http call

I have tried wrapping the whole http call in a try / except block

I am still getting the error showing up in the dev console (which is causing the e2e test to fail)

I am wondering how I can provide a mock `HttpClient` to the protractor tests?

Actual Http call

`return this.http.get<any>( url ).subscribe(...)`

(`this.http` is an instance of angular's `HttpClient`)

spec file:

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging } from 'protractor';

describe( 'workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;

  beforeEach( () => {
    page = new AppPage();
  } );

  it( 'should display login page', () => {
    page.navigateTo();
    expect( page.getLoginTitleText() ).toEqual( 'Welcome to\nApp\nClick below to sign in with Google' );
  } );

  afterEach( async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get( logging.Type.BROWSER );
    expect( logs ).not.toContain( jasmine.objectContaining( {
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    } as logging.Entry ) );
  } );
} );
```

protractor's page object file (`app.po`)

```
import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

export class AppPage {
  public navigateTo() {
    return browser.get( browser.baseUrl ) as Promise<any>;
  }

  public getLoginTitleText() {
    return element( by.css( 'app-root app-login div.login-wrapper form.login section.title' ) )
      .getText() as Promise<string>;
  }
}
```

error in dev console:
[image]

Comment: the more usual way is to make mock backend server with some predefined responses for your api calls, and implement your test based on that. I belive there are a lot of libs that support that kind of implementation. If you still want to mock http module than you will be required to make different config/application for testing

Answer (score 0):

I am just responding to the question about mocking Angular HTTPClient.  Assuming you have Angular version 4 or greater, there is a built in testing module for mocking httpclient called HttpClientTestingModule which you can get from the Testbed.

```
import { AppPage } from './app.po';
import { browser, logging } from 'protractor';
//add these imports:
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

describe( 'workspace-project App', () => {
  let page: AppPage;
  var httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach( () => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
      HttpClientTestingModule
      ]
    });
    page = new AppPage();
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  } );

//add async keyword to test
//mock up the get request by recreating the URL
  it( 'should display login page', async () => {
    let urlPrefix = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + ':' + window.location.port;
    let url = urlPrefix + 'infoo';
    let navigateTo_call = page.navigateTo();
    const request = httpMock.expectOne(url); 
    navigateTo_call.then(res => { 
   //do your checks here
   expect( page.getLoginTitleText() ).toEqual( 'Welcome to\nApp\nClick below to sign in with Google' );
  });
   request.flush("a mock response object");
    
  } );

  afterEach( async () => {
    // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
    const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get( logging.Type.BROWSER );
    expect( logs ).not.toContain( jasmine.objectContaining( {
      level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
    } as logging.Entry ) );
  } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found personally useful is to use `proxy.conf.js` for it which points to assets of the frontend, but with rewritten paths.

There is a conditional response based on `spec === 'user-1'` in the code.

```js
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: ['/api'],
    target: 'http://localhost:4200',
    secure: false,
    bypass: function (req) {
      let spec = '';
      try {
        const url = new URL(req.headers.referer);
        spec = url.searchParams.get('e2e-spec');
      } catch (e) {
        // nothing to do
      }

      if (req.method === 'GET' && req.path === '/api') {
        return '/e2e-api/index.json';
      }
      if (req.method === 'POST' && req.path === '/api/gql') {
        req.method = 'GET';
        if (spec === 'user-1') {
          return '/e2e-api/gql-user-simple.json';
        }
        return '/e2e-api/gql-empty.json';
      }
    },
    logLevel: 'debug',
  },
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

For that we need to add an `e2e` configuration in `angular.json`:

```json
            "e2e": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "apps/ct-frontend/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "apps/ct-frontend/src/environments/environment.e2e.ts"
                }
              ],
              "assets": ["apps/ct-frontend/src/e2e-api"]
            }
```

Here is a repo with the implementation:

- [proxy-e2e.conf.js](https://github.com/satanTime/nx-nestjs-angular-graphql/blob/master/apps/ct-frontend/proxy-e2e.conf.js)
- [assets for e2e](https://github.com/satanTime/nx-nestjs-angular-graphql/tree/master/apps/ct-frontend/src/e2e-api)
- [angular.json](https://github.com/satanTime/nx-nestjs-angular-graphql/blob/master/workspace.json)

You can download it and run e2e tests like that:

- `npm install`
- `npm run e2e ct-frontend-e2e`

to check how it works with fake responses.